# why isn't conditional formatting match working in worksheet?

Tags: excel, match, formula, conditional-formatting

sheet "FATTS" is location of conditional formatting. also location of random number within range B3:Z6000.
matching sheets"FATTS" to sheets"Circulation" Rang("A:A")
formula here:`=MATCH(B3,Circulation!$A$1:$A$6000,0)`
if true format fill blue

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, can you reword your question and provide more details as to what is happening.

Comment: There's a number/text in `Fatts!B3` that you're trying to match in `Circulation!A1:A6000`. Are you positive that number exists in that range?  Also, `MATCH()` returns a row number.  This *might* work, but perhaps you want a `COUNTIF()` instead? `=COUNTIF(Circulation!$A$1:$A$6000,B3)>0`?

Comment: Match returns a number or an error not TRUE/FALSE, use ISNUMBER(): `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(B3,Circulation!$A$1:$A$6000,0))`

Comment: Cell B3 contains "1000" and is formatted as general. on Circulation sheet A1 contains "1000" and is formatted as general as well.

Comment: @ Scott, tried yours and still no color change

Comment: It works for me, https://imgur.com/9p2UQh4

Comment: Make sure you are comparing true numbers to true numbers and not numbers stored as text.

Comment: the sheet that contains the CF has numbers 1000-4500 in random cells B3:z6000. circulation sheet has some of those numbers between"1000-4500" in column "A1:A".  if there is a match between the two sheets, i need it to color the cells on the CF sheet.

Comment: so the opposite of my photo?

Comment: ok so the numbers on the CF sheet was placed on there with a code. cell b3 has "1000" in it. when i select B3 and type "1000" in it then it changed color...?

Comment: Then the numbers on your cf page are not true numbers but numbers stored as text.

Comment: how can i change all of them in one shot?

Comment: Fix the source.  Fix the code that put the numbers there to make them numbers and not strings.

Comment: ok ill give it a try.

Comment: If you get stuck bring the code back and ask a new question relating to that code.

Comment: yeah i will need to get some help on it , thanks everyone!